# functional java - transform by calling a member function

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-java

I'm coming at some functional java from a ruby point of view

in ruby you can do something like this

```
mapped_array = [1,2,3].map(&:to_s)
```

which evaluates out to transforming (map) the array by calling the to_s member function on each object

```
mapped_array = []
[1,2,3].each { |e| mapped_array << e.to_s }
```

I'd like to do something similar in Java, namely transform a list of Product-3 (fj.P3) by calling the _2() method on each object

```
List<P2<Integer, Double>> aListOfP2;
final List<Double> costs = transform(aListOfP2, Converters.<Integer, Double>second());
```

so I have had to define somewhere a method

```
public static final <A,B> Function<P2<A,B>,B> second() {
    return new Function<P2<A, B>, B>() {
        public B apply(final P2<A, B> from) {
            return from._2();
        }
    };
};
```

but then if I want to get the first element, that is another method... if I want to get the second element from a P3, that is another method.

Question is... If there is no mechanism like available in ruby, what is the most generic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check out [__2()](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/P2.java#L300), as in, two underscores.

so your line would become:

```
List<P2<Integer, Double>> aListOfP2;
final List<Double> costs = transform(aListOfP2, P2.<Integer, Double>__2());
```

or you could use something like

```
final List<Double> costs = aListOfP2.map(P2.__2()).map(transform);
```

Comment: That is perfect, the double underscore version is exactly what I wanted! I believe that in order to apply the second syntax I would have to use fj.data.List everywhere instead of the generic java.util.List.